# How can I troubleshoot why my java command is not producing any output?

Tags: java, windows, installation, cmd, java-8

I am trying to install java 8 in my local system. However I seem to not be able to produce any output when I run the `java -version` command. I get a blank response. I tried the command while running cmd as administrator, but had no luck.

```
C:\Users\user>java -version

C:\Users\user>
```

I am using a Windows 11 PC and I am trying to install **jdk1.8.0_202**.

I have checked my env variables and have the following defined:

1. Path : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin
2. JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

I am not sure where else to troubleshoot. I verified that the installation had happened correctly and I tried reinstalling java, but that did not work either.

Comment: Are you sure you execute the correct `java` What does `where java` tell you?

Comment: Here is what `where java` produces :C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe

Comment: I am not sure where the first two entries are from

Comment: That means you have `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` in the `PATH`. If you installed with the Oracle installer, it should run fine (though obviously it doesn't), but otherwise try removing `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` (and possibly `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`) from `PATH`, so only `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin` remains (and other non-Java directories, obviously).

Comment: Does `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe -version` print anything?

Comment: Just to be clear, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe` is most certainly incorrect. That's a file, not the, (expected), directory. You should edit your `Path` environment variable so that it reads as `%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin`. While you're there, I'd advise that the other two entries read as `%CommonProgramFiles%\Oracle\Java\javapath` and `%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Oracle\Java\javapath`, as all system variables are saved to the registry as expandable strings. Then make sure that the location you'd like to use as the default for `java` is listed before the other two.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try restarting your cmd/poweshell? close all instances of
   your CMD/Poweshell then try again or restart your machine.
2. Ensure you configure it on "System Variable"
3. Try echo %JAVA_HOME% and see if its in the right directory

Comment: Yes, I restarted both the cmd and rebooted the system too. I have configured the path in the System Variables (also in User Variables). I have defined `JAVA_HOME` in System variables. It also looks like JAVA_HOME is correctly configured : ```echo %JAVA_HOME%```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

Comment: @KaushikMahadevan i see you typed java -version try  java --version

Comment: I tried both, with '--' and '-'. Neither produces an output.

Comment: Try reinstalling. Why are you using such an old version?

Comment: Well I did try reinstalling. Let me try that again, maybe there was something faulty with the download. Well ideally I wouldn't need such an old version, but there is an application I am trying to set up locally and it is an old one. Using ancient features

Comment: Your old app will likely run fine on the latest JRE unless it's tied in with some other sort of old dependency, such as applets/javascrupt/webstart

Comment: The `JAVA_HOME` variable is **not** used to look up the `java` executable when run from the commandline. That is purely the responsibility of `PATH`. The `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is a convention used by some tools (e.g. Maven, Gradle and others) to find the Java to use _without_ relying on the `PATH`.

Comment: @KaushikMahadevan Even if that ancient application doesn't run on Java 11 or Java 17, it will probably run just fine on Java 8 update 401 (a.k.a. 1.8.0_401), so there is no need to use Java 8 update 202. In fact, using such an old version may actually cause problems, for example with outdated time zone rules and outdated root CA certificates, etc.